# Ошибка при подключении ng add @angular/fire

Tags: javascript, angular

При подключении к Firebase через команду "ng add @angular/fire" выдает такую ошибку "Package "@angular/fire" was found but does not support schematics."
версия angular 16.0.1 / node 18.16.0 / npm 9.5.1
оперативная система macOS 12.6.5

Comment: плохие новости: разработчики данного модуля [не поддерживают angular 16](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3353). можете попробовать поработать на angular 15 или отредактировать @angular/fire/package.json

Comment: Это вроде исправилось но теперь при запуске  ng serve --o  выдает несколько ошибок что модуль не найден @angular/core

Comment: так проект создавали? npx @angular/cli@15 new <project-name>